# ERROR 000732 in Python calling for NetCDF file

Tags: python, raster, netcdf

When executing the following code I keep getting an error and I was unable to fix it. Any ideas what could be wrong? I tried to change the file name to a simpler one but it didn't help. NetCDF data comes from TRMM.

```
import arcpy
import os
dir_name = 'D:\Data'


# Set local variables
inNetCDFFile = "D:\Data\3B43.20090201.7A.HDF.nc"
variable = "precipitation"
XDimension = "nlon"
YDimension = "nlat"
outRasterLayer = "D:\Data\test"
bandDimmension = ""
dimensionValues = ""
valueSelectionMethod = ""

# Execute MakeNetCDFRasterLayer
arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, XDimension, YDimension,
                               outRasterLayer, bandDimmension, dimensionValues, 
                               valueSelectionMethod)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "D:\Google Drive\Gates Project\Data\Climate\TRMM\Python\TRMMNetCDFtoRaster.py", line 19, in <module>
    valueSelectionMethod)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\md.py", line 171, in MakeNetCDFRasterLayer
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input netCDF File: Dataset D:\DataB43.20090201.7A.HDF.nc does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MakeNetCDFRasterLayer).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you are trynig to load a wrong file path:

```
ERROR 000732: Input netCDF File: Dataset D:\DataB43.20090201.7A.HDF.nc does not exist or is not supported
```

If you are on Windows use:

```
inNetCDFFile = "D:\\Data\\3B43.20090201.7A.HDF.nc"
```

or

```
inNetCDFFile = r"D:\Data\3B43.20090201.7A.HDF.nc"
```

Charlie

Comment: Thank you! Now it clearly reads the path, but the output file is not there. How do I fix it, so I actually have a raster file in my folder as a result?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help, I have managed to make a nice script which takes all the NetCDF files from directory and converts them to rasters, so I am going to post it here - others might find it useful! (it is specifically for TRMM rainfall data).

```
import arcpy
import os

dir_name = 'D:\\Data'

# Set local variables
variable = "precipitation"
XDimension = "nlon"
YDimension = "nlat"
bandDimmension = ""
dimensionValues = ""
valueSelectionMethod = "BY_VALUE"


# Loop that converts NetCDF files from directory and converts to .img rasters:
dir_name = 'D:\\Data'
for filename in os.listdir(dir_name):
    if not filename.endswith(".nc"): continue
    full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, filename)
    outRaster = '%s.img' % (full_path,)
    fileroot = filename[0:(len(filename)-10)]   
    outRasterLayer = dir_name + "\\" + fileroot
    arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(full_path, variable, XDimension, YDimension,
                               outRasterLayer, bandDimmension, dimensionValues, 
                               valueSelectionMethod)
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(outRasterLayer,outRaster)
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `arcpy` but the [example](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/multidimension/make-netcdf-raster-layer.htm) uses foward slashes, not backslashes.  I'd try

```
inNetCDFFile = "D:/Data/3B43.20090201.7A.HDF.nc"
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it clearly reads the path, but the output file is not there. How do I fix it, so I actually have a raster file in my folder as a result?

Comment: The outRasterLayer is just a layer, not a file.  You really should read the manual.  See: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/save-to-layer-file.htm